# IDLE Factor determination

Tags: aircraft-performance, thrust, descent, fms

The Flight Management System (FMS) utilises the Idle Factor to modify the computation of the vertical profile whilst descending.

During this phase, the FMS calculates the vertical profile and predictions from the Top of Descent (TOD). Depending on the value of the IDLE factor, the FMS modifies the position of the TOD and computes a vertical profile based on the given thrust (IDLE + DELTA). Therefore, the IDLE factor has a direct impact on the computation of the vertical profile and the aircraft's ability to maintain the vertical profile.

Does anyone have practical advice for determining the appropriate idle factor value (what parameters to look at, how to analyze them, etc.)? Providing learning materials or resources would be appreciated, as I do not want this to appear as homework assistance.

P.S. English is not my first language. I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Are you working on writing FMS algorithms? What is the reason you need to determine this value?

Comment: @RalphJ Airline flight ops departments may need to update the IDLE factor as the engine ages and is replaced. Certain mods and aircraft operating conditions, like galleys and IFE that draw large electrical currents, will affect IDLE. Getting the FMS predictions right [will save fuel](https://www.fabec.eu/images/registrations/brussels2020/3%20-%20Wizz%20%20Air.pdf).

Comment: @user71659 Okay, is that what the OP is working on? Because if so, I'd expect that the engineers there might already have some resources, and if they don't then the manufacturer of their aircraft surely does.  How much data and knowledge is the OP starting out with?  Needing to write a first cut at hypothetical parameters for generalized software is a whole different challenge than taking existing parameters and adjusting them for a particular change, and giving us an idea of what stage of the problem he's at may help the OP get a better answer here.

Comment: @RalphJ The reason for the Idle Factor determination is proper fuel prediction and adjusting the Top of Descent. Refer to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAeL7ekh7jQ. The video says that Flight OPS team is the one to determine the Idle Factor, but the only solution they mention is outsourcing this through Navblue or other services. At this stage I am just trying to understand how this works as nobody in my company knows and never did this before.